# Convert String to two chars and reverse the two chars

Tags: string, delphi, split, reverse

Hello I want to split a simple string into a group of two characters then reverse them.

For example MyStringToBeReversed to two charachters each My St ri ng To Be Re ve rs ed
then reverse each splited two charachters to :
St := ts
ri := ir
etc ...

Here's the code I'm using but it only displays one charachter on memo lines

```
     procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
     var
        MyString: string;
        i: integer;
        k: integer;
        j: integer;
     begin
          MyString:= Edit1.Text;

         for i:= 1 to length(MyString) do
         Memo1.Lines.Add(MyString[i]);
     //    Move(Str[1], MyString, Length(Str));

     end;
     end.
```

Comment: So `Test string` should become `eTtss rtnig`?

Comment: well i'm not sure let's test that using numbers it's better
for example 010203040506
would be 102030405060

Comment: Okay. So the answer to my Q is probably "yes". What happens if the input string is not of even length?

Comment: `function F(const S: string): string;
begin
  Result := S;
  for var i := 0 to S.Length div 2 - 1 do
  begin
    Result[2*i + 1] := S[2*i + 2];
    Result[2*i + 2] := S[2*i + 1];
  end;
end;`

Comment: Note that `Move()` deals in bytes, not characters. `SizeOf(Char)` is 2 bytes in Delphi 2009 and later

Comment: let's say we could add a letter A to it

Comment: You need to know what the specification is before coding. Do you?

Comment: well i do , my problem is how to interpret it , i already tried many methods found in the internet , and as my low level of coding i couldn't do it correctly sorry

Comment: What happens when the input string is not of even length?

Comment: already answered Andreas Rejbrand  , @ David Heffernan we could add a letter A to the non even char
so becomes  something like 01 02 03 04 05 A6 or 6A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need

```
function ReverseEachTwoChars(AInput : string) : string;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  if(Odd(Length(AInput))) then
  begin
    SetLength(AInput, Length(AInput) + 1);
    AInput[Length(AInput)] := 'A';
  end;

  SetLength(Result, Length(AInput));
  i := 1;
  while(i < Length(Result)) do
  begin
    Result[i] := AInput[i + 1];
    Result[i + 1] := AInput[i];
    Inc(i, 2);
  end;
end;
```

Test:

```
ShowMessage(ReverseEachTwoChars('010203040506'));
```

Output:

```
102030405060
```

Comment: Thanks , Simple function to do the job
let's say i want to add the letter A to the first Char for example 
1 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 to 
A1 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 how can i proceed ?

Comment: @coolirc Why don't you try to do this yourself?

Comment: @David , i'm already on it thanks for help